# Javascript code is not created inside MVC3 Razor foreach loop !!?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is code fragment:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Column1</th>
           <th>Column2</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>Value1</td>
           <td>Value2</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     <table>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () { $("table").highchartTable(); });
     </script>
}
```

Why javascript code is not created inside MVC3 Razor foreach loop ?
There must be multiple javasctipt codes created.

However, the resulting HTML doesnt have javascript at all.

Any ideas ??

Thank you.

Comment: You only need to render it once if you are going to call that function on all table tags.

Comment: Are you sure the javascript isn't in the resulting HTML document? Have you viewed the source in the browser? I can see maybe why your javascript function isn't executing, but I would expect the javascript to be there. Also, do you know for sure that there is at least 1 item in your collection? If there are none, then nothing in the loop will get rendered.

Comment: This is simplified version. The function will be called on each table, I will replace it with table id. Model has nothing to do with my question. The tables are created for each item in the Model which is Ienumerable<T>. The problem is <script> block is not created. Why?

Comment: Yes, Brian, there are 10 item in my collection, I get 10 tables created, bot no <script> block. View source will not show this content since it is dynamically inserted by js ajax call. But in Firefox, I can see the resulting HTML in Firebug in debug mode.

Comment: frictionlesspulley, what for? and how? and... what for ??